# Explanatory の/ん in questions with interrogatives: Two conflicting rules

Tags: grammar, particle-の, questions, interrogatives

I'm working through [this grammar book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%BA%B5-%E5%8A%9F%E9%9B%84/dp/4883191559/), which goes into a lot of detail about the grammar of questions and when the explanatory の/ん needs to be included.  On pg. 284, the book says that a question must include の/ん if the following is true:

> 疑問文中に疑問語 (疑問詞) が含まれている (疑問語疑問文の) 場合

With more details further down the page:

> なお、疑問語 (疑問詞) を含んでいてもその疑問語 (疑問詞) が述語に含まれているときは名詞文と同じ構造になるので、「のだ」は必要ではありません。

In summary, a question containing an interrogative that isn't the final predicate must include の/ん.  Examples: 「田中さんは何を見た**の**ですか。」「田中さんが見たのは何ですか。」(The book also notes that this rule isn't always followed in beginner Japanese language education, even though sentences that don't follow this rule would sound unnatural to native speakers.)

Edit: Just to clarify further, this rule only applies to questions as part of a sentence's main clause.  The book notes that relative clauses would not apply. Example: 「私の留守中に**だれが来たか**教えてください。」

But, on pg. 287, the book lists the following question forms as valid (where ↑ = a rising tone):

> だれが来ますか。
> だれが来ましたか。
> だれが来ます↑。
> だれが来ました↑。
> だれが来る↑。
> だれが来た↑。

These two pages seem to contradict each other. How can the structures on pg. 287 be valid without の/ん, if the rule on pg. 284 is true?  The book doesn't clarify this, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @A.Ellett, ん？  田中さんは何を見たのですか means "What did Tanaka see?"

Comment: @Chocolate  thanks.  sometimes i'm just too much in my English-speaking head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They indeed seem to contradict each other. However, the rules described in the preceding pages should not be taken too literally. The book itself offers the following caveat in p286.

> 本来「のだ」が必要とされる文で「のだ」が使われないことがあります。この場合、「のだ」を使っても問題はないので、学習者は「「のだ」が不要になることもある」ということを知っていれば十分です。

As for the examples you copied from p287, the authors probably needed a few examples with an interrogative that end with か (without の) in order to demonstrate だれが｛来る／来た｝か as invalid in contrast to あの映画を｛見るか／見たか｝ with no interrogative.

While these questions are not exactly invalid, they sound somewhat *detached* from the situation, as if the speaker is interrogating someone for the purpose of obtaining a fact, indifferent to the situation of that person. Depending on the context, they could even sound a little intimidating.

The following equivalents with ん or の sound more natural in most cases.

> だれが来る**ん**ですか。
> だれが来た**ん**ですか。
> だれが来る**の**↑。
> だれが来た**の**↑。

The difference is the presence or absence of 前提 and 焦点 as the book puts them. The *who* part gets focused by の or ん against the background knowledge that someone will, has, or did come and only their identity is unknown. I suppose it is due to the lack of this focus that questions with interrogatives sound unnatural unless they also contain の or ん.

Answer (score 0):

田中さんは何を見た↑。　　　 ⇒"見た" is a plain-form. You don't need "のだ".
田中さんは何を見たのですか。⇒"見た" is a plain-form. To make this a polite form, you need "のだ".
田中さんが見たのは何↑。　　 ⇒This is a noun sentence, and "何" is a plain-form. You don't need "のだ".
田中さんが見たのは何ですか。⇒This is a noun sentence, and "何" is a plain-form. To make this a polite form, you need "です".

In the Plain-form, "のだ" or "です" are not necessary, while in the polite form, "のだ" or "です" are necessary.

だれが来ますか。　⇒Masu-form, Polite-form, No need for "のだ".
だれが来ましたか。⇒Masu-form, Polite-form, No need for "のだ".
だれが来ます↑。　 ⇒Masu-form, Polite-form, No need for "のだ".
だれが来ました↑。 ⇒Masu-form, Polite-form, No need for "のだ".
だれが来る↑。　　 ⇒Root-form, Plain-form, No need for "のだ".
だれが来た↑。　　 ⇒Ta  -form, Plain-form, No need for "のだ".

The word "Masu" implies politeness. so you don't need "のだ".